# Send POST variables to a second script on another server

Tags: php, paypal

Okay, so on a website I'm developing, I need to add a PayPal checkout. I've not done a website with online payments before, so I'm new to it, but I think I understand how it works. However, I'm not too sure how to set up the form submission part.

PayPal offer premade button forms, which I'm going to use for this. The button is set up so on submit, it will go to a script on the PayPal servers. However, I want to pass the variables onto a PHP script of my own first, to save them into a database before the user is directed to PayPal's own checkout/pay system.

I know you can send a custom variable through the system, which PayPal send to your IPN listener, however I have a lot of variables that for different reasons, I want stored into a database before the user pays, not after.

So basically:
`User fills out form and sumbits > PHP saves form data > Variables are past onto the PayPal server using POST method without the user having to go to a second page before they see the PayPal page`

Not sure if I've worded that very well, but hopefully you get my point. I simply want to send variables form one PHP script to another using POST variables.

Note: As I can't edit the PayPal script, session variables are not an option, neither are GET variables. Has to be POST

Also, my server has PHP version 5.3 and supports cURL and all that stuff

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: I am yet to try anything, as I don't want to waste my time coding something that won't work. I just simply want to know if there is a method of posting variables from one script to another, you know?

Comment: The answer to that question is "yes", there is a method.

Comment: In which case, as follow up question, where abouts would I find information about doing this? :)

Comment: By searching using a tool that is not StackOverlow. ;-)

Comment: In my defence, I've been searching all day ;)

Comment: Try the [developer reference](https://developer.paypal.com/) which would have samples and SDKs for you to tinker with. The above can be achieved in different ways, though the approach maybe different depending on which API/payment call you want to do. Hth.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you edit the PayPal script?  It would be very simple to build a form, set the action of it to your own PHP, and within that PHP set all the data to session vars, save it to your database, etc.

Then you can put together a payment request string using the [cart upload command method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/) that PayPal provides and redirect the user to PayPal accordingly, so all they'd see is PayPal.  They wouldn't see anything with your "processor" script.

Even better would be to use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) as they provide more freedom and functionality to customize things how you want than Payments Standard does.

Since you're working with PHP you may be interested in my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It would make Express Checkout calls very simple for you, and you can do whatever you need to do with your database within those scripts.